# Remove Duplicates from ArrayList filled with POJOs

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList filled POJOs and I want to remove all POJOs, which have a duplicate variable. This is the POJO:

```
public static class UrlStore {

    public String url;
    public String data;

    public UrlStore(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

My way to remove duplicate "url"-variables in the `ArrayList<UrlStore>` is to iterate through the list and to remove those duplicates. It was said to me that I could simply use a `Set` to do this, but I can't figure out how to use it with an ArrayList containing POJOs. Or do you have even a better way?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Add an `equals` and `hashCode` method to your POJO, then just create a `Set` from the `List` (with `Set.addAll`) and it will automatically remove the duplicates.

Comment: Just convert the list to set and enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package test.urlstore;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class DuplicateDemo{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<UrlStore> urlStores = new ArrayList<UrlStore>();
        UrlStore usg = new UrlStore("google");
        UrlStore usy = new UrlStore("yahoo");
        UrlStore usb = new UrlStore("bing");
        UrlStore usa = new UrlStore("ask");
        UrlStore usd = new UrlStore("duckduckgo");


        usg.setData("mail");
        urlStores.add(usg);
        usg = new UrlStore("google");
        usg.setData("search");
        urlStores.add(usg);
        usg = new UrlStore("google");
        usg.setData("doc");
        urlStores.add(usg);
        usg = new UrlStore("google");
        usg.setData("search");
        urlStores.add(usg);
        usg = new UrlStore("google");
        usy.setData("search");
        urlStores.add(usy);
        usy.setData("search");
        urlStores.add(usy);
        usb.setData("search");
        urlStores.add(usb);
        usb.setData("search");
        urlStores.add(usb);
        usa.setData("search");
        urlStores.add(usa);
        usd.setData("search");
        urlStores.add(usd);

        System.out.println("before removing duplicates");
        // before removing duplicates
        for (Iterator iterator = urlStores.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            UrlStore urlStore = (UrlStore) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(urlStore.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nafter removing duplicates");
        //removing duplicates
         Set<UrlStore> uniqueUrlStores = new HashSet<UrlStore>(urlStores);

         //After removing duplicates
         for (Iterator iterator = uniqueUrlStores.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            UrlStore urlStore = (UrlStore) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(urlStore.toString());

        }

    }



    static class UrlStore {

        public String url;
        public String data;

        public UrlStore(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UrlStore [url=" + url + ", data=" + data + "]";
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((data == null) ? 0 : data.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((url == null) ? 0 : url.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            UrlStore other = (UrlStore) obj;
            if (data == null) {
                if (other.data != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!data.equals(other.data))
                return false;
            if (url == null) {
                if (other.url != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!url.equals(other.url))
                return false;
            return true;
        }


    }   
}
```

Comment: Wow.. alot of thanks for the work! A little bit toooo much, but it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 11):

You can override the [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) methods in your POJO and pass the `List<UrlStore>` to the `Set`.

```
 List<UrlStore> listOfUrlStore = ......
 Set<UrlStore> foo = new HashSet<UrlStore>(listOfUrlStore);
```

I have used a simple [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) here , the correct implementation of [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) depends on your requirement. You can even convert the `Set` back to the `List` .

```
 listOfUrlStore.clear();
 listOfUrlStore.addAll(foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Override hashCode() and equals() in your POJO and then:

```
List<URLStore>() list = //Your list;
Set<URLStore> set =new HashSet<URLStore>(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to override the `equals` method of your POJO.
One this is done, you could use `contains` method of `List` to check if your object is in the list before add it.
For the `Set`, you don't have to use it **with** the list, it **replace** the list. You can populate a `Set` from a `List` with `addAll(Collection c)`